# Scrollable table with non scrolling header

Tags: html, css, pug

I am using jade to develop a webpage which has a table and I have made it scrollable. How do I make it such that the header doesn't scroll along with the content of the table?

```
div(class='scrollit')  
    table.table.table-striped-table-bordered(id='table1')
      tr
        td Header 1
        td Header 2
        td Header 3
      - for(var rule in obj)
        tr
          td 
            input(type='checkbox')
          td 
            input(type='checkbox')
          td
            input(type='checkbox')
```

css:

```
.scrollit {
    overflow:scroll;
    height:500px;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1 - Example

Is this what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/jrLw4/38/

---

### 2 - Explanation

Basically what is being done here is one **table, which has the scrolling content, and another table, that represents the heading of that content.**

*You can't actually achieve this effect by using only one table, because the table elements are all connected. In order to get the fixed effect of the heading working properly, you would need to separate these elements.*

So after doing what you need with both elements (heading and content) in different `table` elements, you just wrap it up in a `div` (or any other HTML container element) and use the typical `position: fixed` trick within that wrapper element.

---

### 3 - Code

HTML

```
<div id="table-wrapper">
    <table id="table-head">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>One</td>
                <td>Two</td>
                <td>Three</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <div id="table-wrapper-scroll">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>This</td>
                    <td>is a</td>
                    <td>row</td>
                </tr>

[[lots of content]]

                <tr>
                    <td>This</td>
                    <td>is a</td>
                    <td>row</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#table-wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
#table-wrapper-scroll{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
#table-head {
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    color: #f00;
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f00;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
#table-wrapper-scroll > table{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Upvoting for taking a minute to change `td>header>...` to `thead>tr>th`

Comment: I tried using the code in the jsfiddle and increased the number of headers to 6, and for the table rows I had 3 checkboxes and 3 textboxes. They did not align properly with the header. How do I get them to align properly?

Comment: @AndroidDev93 you should use CSS to control the sizing of the cells on the header and on the content at the same time. The cell A of the content table should have the same class as the cell A on the Heading table ;)